# <embed> SVG or TIFF in Firefox 3

Tags: image, firefox, svg, tiff

Firefox has native support for SVG. However, I have a web page where the SVG graphig is `<embed>`ed, and a plugin is requested to show it.

When I click on the plugin icon, no plugin is proposed by FF.

Questions:

- Is there such a plugin?
- Is there a way to make FF display embedded SVGs using its native support without installing a plugin?

The same happens with TIFF files.

**UPDATE:**

Code:

```
<td align="left">
<p>
    <embed
        src="/file-server/review/AttachedFilesServlet.servlet?attachedFileId=28604|original=additional-docs/medicine.svg"
        alt="SVG"> Image SVG
</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a few issues with this recently. The way that I managed to make it work was using the embed function (I was initially using html5, which firefox 3.6 doesnt support inline svg, yet)

The syntax used was, where workspace contains just SVG code:

```
<embed src="workspace.svg" width="500" height="500" />
```

The above code shouldn't need a plugin, and didn't when I used it. The advantage of using `<embed>` rather than `<object>` is because it allows you to run scripts. If your syntax is slightly different then that could be your issue. If your syntax is the same, post your code as a whole so we can have a look.

Adobe used to supply a plugin but they no longer give support for it so it is wise not to use it.

Edit in response to code posting by OP:

There are only two reasons I can think of, as to why your code isnt working, but not sure if they would actually make a difference:

a) Closing the embed tag (almost definetly not the problem, but is good practice to do so anyway).

b) As I cant see your servlet I cant assume that you have not set the content type to be image/svg+. That could be an issue.

```
res.setContentType("image/svg+xml");
```

Comment: Likewise I added more content.

Comment: Just to be clear, the correct mimetype for svg is and has always been `"image/svg+xml"`.